# How to get all parts of an array in your html?

Tags: javascript

I got this code:

```
var countryBox = document.getElementById('land');
var landen = response;
for(var i=0; i< landen.length; i++){
    var a = (landen[i].venue.country);
    countryBox.innerHTML = a;
}
```

but now i only get the last country on my screen. What did I do wrong? How do I get all of the countries on my screen?

Comment: you should append all of them to a variable and finally assign it to the innerHTML; Right now, every time you iterate in the loop you overwrite it!

Comment: Can you share some sample data as well please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overwriting `countryBox.innerHTML` in each iteration instead of appending to it. The right way would be:

```
countryBox.innerHTML += a;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the last Element as Each time :

`countryBox.innerHTML = a`

will take Only single `a` value,

**So you need to just use concatanation or Appending the string**

`countryBox.innerHTML += a;`

Will Work!

Answer (score 0):

Few things

```
var countryBox = document.getElementById('land');
var landen = response, a = "", landenLength = landen.length;
for(var i=0; i< landenLength; i++){
    // Add a comma after every country's name
    if(i > 0){
      a += ",";
    }
    a += landen[i].venue.country;
}
// After a is formed, outside the loop, then put it in the html
countryBox.innerHTML = a;
```

OR

I am not sure but try this out too :

```
// Returns only country names
var countryArray = landen.map((landen_a, index, landen) => {return landen.venue.country});
countryArray = countryArray.join(","); // countryArray becomes a string
countryBox.innerHTML = countryArray;
```